# How to stream kudu logs in Azure webapp using Azure AD authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to stream logs exposed by an Azure web application using kudu streaming endpoint, eg. `curl https://my-webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream`. Of course, this does not work and returns a 401 because I do not pass authentication. I found references on the web on how to authenticate using BasicAuth (eg. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) but not using Azure AD provide token. If I try to authenticate using `az account get-access-token --resource=...` I don't know what resource to pass: Using the webapp's resource URL does not work.

What I would like to be able to do is simply something like:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(... get somehow token ...)" https://my-webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/logs/streaming
```

and get a live stream of logs for my webapp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid you can't, you can just call the APIs which are secured by Azure AD with the access token, but the Kudu API is not secured by Azure AD, it uses the basic auth as you know.

In your case, if you don't want to expose the publish profile(username and password) of your web app in the command, my workaround is to use the Azure CLI to get them directly and pass them to the `curl` command. So even if someone gets the script, he will not be able to access the logstream without permission in your web app.

```
username=$(az webapp deployment list-publishing-credentials --name joywebapp --resource-group <grou-name> --query publishingUserName -o tsv)
password=$(az webapp deployment list-publishing-credentials --name joywebapp --resource-group <grou-name> --query publishingPassword -o tsv)  
curl -u "$username:$password" https://joywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream
```

[image]

Comment: This looked promising, I tried it but unfortunately I still get a 401 even though I can retrieve the publishingUserName and publishingPassword properties. Or is the password base64 encoded?

Comment: @insitu Where did you run the script? Powershell or bash? Did you change the webapp name to yours?

Comment: :) Yes, I did change the webapp name. Ran it from bash on a Mac, I can retrieve the parameters correctly and they are well-defined, but curl failed with a 401

Comment: It's pretty silly everything can be done in Azure using OAuth2 based authentication but for these simple things :(

Comment: @insitu Well, I have no Mac to test for you, could you have a try in the Azure Cloud Shell? https://shell.azure.com/ Choose the mode with `Bash`.

Comment: doh :-o It's working now, from both environments. PEBKAC I guess... Thanks for the answer and pushing me around to try again!

Comment: For others coming here wanting to do this, 
Joy Wang's 2020 answer actually works.
There may be other issues causing it to fail,
but I needed this, and could achieve 'curl tail' by doing what Joy Wang suggested
(getting username and pwd, then calling curl with -u).